# Как узнать, как настроены на push/pull локальные ветки?

Tags: git, git-branch

Есть локальный репозиторий git, добавлен один или несколько удалённых (remote) репозиториев.
В репозитории несколько локальных веток.

Как быстро и удобно посмотреть, в какие ветки каких remote-ов они настроены на push и pull?

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950725/how-do-i-get-git-to-show-me-which-branches-are-tracking-what

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Pull

Основную информацию можно получить такой командой:

```
$ git branch -vv
  bar    b6c2674 ...
  buzz   4422cf4 [origin/buzz: ahead 4] ...
  fizz   9ea2227 [origin/fizz: behind 1] ...
* foo    04c196f [origin/foo: gone] ...
  master 4422cf4 [origin/master] ...
```

Подробнее о различных вариантах вывода:

- Ветка bar не имеет соответствующей удалённой ветки.

  ```
    bar    b6c2674 ...
  ```
- Ветка buzz настроена на pull из ветки buzz репозитория origin, которая локально представлена веткой origin/buzz и опережает её на 4 коммита.

  ```
    buzz   4422cf4 [origin/buzz: ahead 4] ...
  ```
- Ветка fizz настроена на pull из ветки origin/fizz и остаёт на 1 коммит.

  ```
    fizz   9ea2227 [origin/fizz: behind 1] ...
  ```
- Ветка foo настроена на pull из ветки origin/foo, но в репозитории origin больше нет ветки foo. Звёздочка `*` означает, что в данный момент мы находимся на ветке `foo`.

  ```
  * foo    04c196f [origin/foo: gone] ...
  ```
- Ветка master настроена на pull из ветки origin/master и полностью ей соответствует.

  ```
  master   4422cf4 [origin/master] ...
  ```

## Push

Прошлый способ не даёт информации о настройке push.
Обычно эти настройки идентичны, но можно сделать иначе.
Поэтому давайте будем подозревать худшее, особенно если смотрим на ветки на чужой машине.

```
git remote show origin
```

Эта команда показывает достаточно много информации об *одном* удалённом репозитории, включая настройки tracking для веток.